# Is it bad practice to have a macro definition return a value for a function?

Tags: c++, c, macros

Using a macro defined to conditionally return a value has a disadvantage where it is not apparent from only looking at the client code might exit at the point of the macro.

The use case I am considering is writing a value and error checking, like so:

```
#define WRITE_CHK(file, param)\
if (!write_that_returns_zero_on_fail(file, param)) {\
   handle_error();\
   return false;\
}
```

client code:

```
bool myfunc()
{
   ...
   WRITE_CHK(file, param) // function might return here
   ...
   return true;
}
```

I am curious if the benefits of the macro (which would be used in many places in my code) would outweigh the disadvantage mentioned above.
Are there preferred alternatives besides simply expanding (not using the macro)?

Comment: Well, the usual C++ approach is to have the "write" function itself throw an exception on error, instead of constantly checking return codes.  Has the same "potentially surprising early return" problem, but so does any program using exceptions...

Comment: I want a solution that is c compatible

Comment: Please let me know why my question is downvoted so I can improve future ones

Comment: People have probably downvoted your question because it appears to be subjective. Questions that start with "Is it bad practice" generally get a bad rap around here. In fact, someone has flagged it as "not constructive" or off-topic. I happen to disagree with that, because I think you're asking a useful question here and there *are* good answers (like Oli's) that aren't simply personal opinion or likely to incite argument. I'm in favor of leaving this open, but you might want to reword the title a little.

Comment: Another issue with your macro is the unusual syntax at the calling side. It doesn't replace a proper statement and you have the dangling `else` problem. You could just append `else (void)0` to get rid of both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard answer is "don't use macros"; but that's often slightly simplistic.  There are sometimes cases where they can greatly cut down on the boilerplate verbosity that you'd otherwise have.

So, why not encode the fact into the macro name?  e.g. `WRITE_OR_RETURN_ON_FAILURE`.  It may be slightly verbose, but it's much less likely to trip up readers of your code.

Comment: I wanna give you +0.5 here. Your suggestion is perfectly valid but the return-in-macro approach has a smell and a better answer would involve some alternate approach. +1 anyway. :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, I considered that.  But sometimes you really just want to wrap up that tedious pattern, and a helper function just won't do it.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, this way lie dragons.

Comment: Yes, thanks for understanding the usage and for the valid advice.  Naming can do quite a lot!

Comment: Agreed - as long as the macro name includes the verb `RETURN` in it, that should be sufficient warning.

Answer (score 3):

Hiding control flow inside a macro is not used very commonly, so it can be confusing to developers who will have to understand or debug your code.

I would recommend against using macros totally, but if you have to use them ensure that the control flow part is explicit.

```
// assume handle_error returns true
#define WRITE_FAILED(file, param)\
(!write_that_returns_zero_on_fail(file, param) && handle_error())

// macro usage
if(WRITE_FAILED(file, param))
{
    return;
}
```

Another question to ask yourself would be -- why do you want to use macros here anyway? If it was to hide the control flow then that's not a good idea. Is there another reason?

Answer (score 1):

Make a 2-step macro:

```
#define WRITE_CHK_(file, param, HANDLER)\
if (!write_that_returns_zero_on_fail(file, param)) {\
    handle_error();\
    HANDLER\
}

#define RFALSE return false;

#define WRITE_CHK(file, param) WRITE_CHK_(file, param, RFALSE)
```

Then you can make other wrappers if you need a similar check elsewhere (or directly use `WRITE_CHK(file, param, return false)`)

Comment: How does that address the issue?

Comment: @Oli If you want to make it manifest that you are returning false, you can just use something like `WRITE_CHK(file, param, return false)`.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  I think your answer would be better if it suggested that approach!

Comment: @Oli edited.  I use this macro pattern so many times its second nature

Comment: the answer itself is convoluted but through Oli's comments and your answer I think I see what you are saying.  It is interesting, thanks.

Comment: The problem with this is that `RFALSE` is just *noise*. That's hardly any shorter than `return false;` and nowhere *near* as descriptive or easy to read. The macro in the question is acceptable, because it actually does hide some redundant boilerplate code and make things easier to read. `RFALSE` is an example of a bad, useless macro.

Comment: This is a bad macro. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it's bad. Use a `goto`.

```
 #define fail_unless(x) do {if(!(x)) goto fail;} while (0)

 int foo()
 {
     fail_unless( my_write(...) );
     fail_unless( bar() );
     return 0;
 fail:
     cleanup();
     return -1;
 }
```

**Edit**: if you're downvoting because you don't understand what that while loop is doing there, you should just have asked. It is a standard technique for making sure a C macro acts as a single statement in any context. If your macro expands to an if statement (like the macros in the other, upvoted answers), then you get unexpected side effects, eg:

```
 #define DONT_DO_THIS(x) if (!x) { foo; }

 if (a) DONT_DO_THIS(x)
 else something_else();
```

You'd expect something_else to be executed when `!a`, but what the macro actually expands to is:

```
 if (a)
     if (!x) { foo;}
     else something_else();
```

And something_else is executed when `a && x`, not when `!a` as the programmer intended.

Comment: Are you serious?  How is this any better at eliminating surprise?

Comment: Of course I'm serious. Both exit points in the function are visible, and the `fail` label tells you what's going on. Also, instead of using macros like fsmc's `WRITE_CHK`, which writes and checks and potentially returns (and then a similar `BAR_CHK` for bar, etc.), there is a single `CHECK` macro. I called it that to follow his example, but I would use something like `fail_check`, strengthening the link between the macro and the label.

Comment: @Foo Bah it generalizes much better than your own answer.

Comment: I don't think that your explanation of the standard pattern of using a `while` loop is why *anyone* downvoted this...

Comment: Obviously it couldn't be, since the explanation came after the downvotes. What's your point?