# Return from calling function inside lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, macros, syntactic-sugar

Lambdas are an awesome way to create reusable code inside a function/method without polluting the parent class. They're a very functional replacement for C-style macros most of the time.

However, there's one bit of syntactic sugar from macros that I can't seem to replicate with a lambda, and that's the ability to exit from the containing function. For example, if I need to return while checking the range of a series of `int`s, I can do that easily with a macro:

```
const int xmin(1), xmax(5);
#define CHECK_RANGE(x) { if((x) < xmin || (x) > xmax) return false; }

bool myFunc(int myint) {
    CHECK_RANGE(myint);
    int anotherint = myint + 2;
    CHECK_RANGE(anotherint);
    return true;
}
```

Obviously this is an oversimplified example, but the basic premise is that I'm performing the same check over and over on different variables, and I think it's more readable to encapsulate the check and related exits. Still, I know that [macros aren't very safe](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html), especially when they get really complex. However, as far as I can tell, trying to do the equivalent lambda requires awkward additional checks like so:

```
const int xmin(1), xmax(5);
auto check_range = [&](int x) -> bool { return !(x < xmin || x > xmax); };

bool myFunc(int myint) {
    if(!check_range(myint)) return false;
    int anotherint = myint + 2;
    if(!check_range(anotherint)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with a lambda? Or am I missing some alternative solution?

**Edit:** I recognize that [returning from inside a macro is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7004327/1666676) unless [significant precautions are taken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7004345/1666676). I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: _there's one bit of syntactic sugar_ - yes, to make the code incomprehensible.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. It would be nice if there were some way to do this, but there is not as of this time

Comment: I'll side with Justin before thinking too much about how [`std::longjmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp) could help.

Comment: @Quentin I'll prefer macros to longjmp. But actually, the only bad thing about macro is that it doesn't check types and syntax. macro generates source code your compiler process after, there is NO insecurity if macro used right.  There are pitfalls in way how you write macro, e.g. parameters being reused with incremental operator.. or absence of parents around those expressions.

Comment: You could try to set this up with exceptions, which depending on use case might be preferable to `longjmp`.

Comment: _However, there's one bit of syntactic sugar..._ -- that's a funny way of spelling "thankfully"

Comment: @manni66 Maybe in some situations, but in this case it seems _much_ clearer in this situation (to me, anyway) to use a macro. Another example is checking an iostream's state after every read. Seems much more readable to me to encapsulate the read with the state check, especially when a later change requires modifying every state check.

Comment: A macro named CHECK_RANGE that inserts a return into the code is definitely not cleaner.

Comment: @Swift yeah, that was a somewhat tongue-in-cheek suggestion so that the people who know `std::setjmp` could scare themselves -- I'd rather use a macro as well ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct--there's no way to return from the caller from inside a lambda. Since a lambda can be captured and stored to be called later, from inside an arbitrary caller, doing so would result in unpredictable behavior.

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(std::function<void(int)> const& callMeLater) : func(callMeLater) {}
    void CallIt(int* arr, int count)
    {
        for (index = count; index--;)
            func(count);
        // do other stuff here.
    }
    std::function<void(int)> func;
};

int main()
{
    auto find3 = [](int arr) 
    {
        if (arr == 3)
            return_from_caller; // making up syntax here.
    };

    Foo foo(find3);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to do this with a lambda?

Not exactly like the macro but your lambda, instead of returning a `bool`, can `throw` a special exception (of type `bool`, by example)

```
auto check_range
   = [](int x) { if ( (x < xmin) || (x > xmax) ) throw bool{false}; };
```

and the function `myFunc()` can intercept this special type

```
bool myFunc (int myint)
 {
   try
    {
      check_range(myint);
      int anotherint = myint + 2;
      check_range(anotherint);
      return true;
    }
   catch ( bool e )
    { return e; }
 }
```

For a single `check_range()` call, this is (I suppose) a bad idea; if you have a lot of calls, I suppose can be interesting.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int xmin{1}, xmax{5};

auto check_range
   = [](int x) { if ( (x < xmin) || (x > xmax) ) throw bool{false}; };

bool myFunc (int myint)
 {
   try
    {
      check_range(myint);
      int anotherint = myint + 2;
      check_range(anotherint);
      return true;
    }
   catch ( bool e )
    { return e; }
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << myFunc(0) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << myFunc(3) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << myFunc(7) << std::endl; // print 0
 }
```

Comment: Rather than throw a `bool`, it is generally more preferred (and easier to read) to throw a custom `struct`/`class` instead, especially run that is derived from `std::exception` (like `std::out_of_range` or `std::range_error`), and then catch that instead and use `return false` directly.

Comment: +1 because this is the solution I'm looking for, but the accepted answer addresses the question itself better.

Answer (score 1):

No better way to do this than just to use the return value of the lambda and then `return` from the calling function.  Macros are ew for this.

As it stands in C++, that is the idiomatic way to exit from a function that uses another condition to determine whether or not to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Not C++11, but people have hacked C++2a coroutines to basically do this.

It would look a bit like:

```
co_await check_range(foo);
```

where the `co_await` keyword indicates that in some cases, this coroutine could return early with an incomplete result.  In your cases, this incomplete result would be non-resumabable error.

The playing around I saw was with optionals, and required using a shared ptr, but things may improve before it is standardized.